# how do I keep my videos from speeding up?

Tags: edit-mode, video, audio

When I am saving videos in the Video Editing part the video itself is going at twice the speed while the audio stays the same. I  can't seem to fix it and have no idea what to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why will audio and video not sync in rendered video file?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2654/why-will-audio-and-video-not-sync-in-rendered-video-file)

Comment: Check to make sure that your framerates line up. If the framerate of your imported video is different from your scene settings, that could cause this.